# Failed to compile Module parse failed: Unexpected character, when importing or accessing docx file reactjs

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-router, docx

I want a button who is going to download a docx file on click, the file is static and has in the images/downloads directory following I have tried and got no luck.

First, try -

```
 <a href={require("../../images/downloads/Gate-Pass-Moving-in.docx")}
    className="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
    download >
     Download
 </a>
```

Second try -

```
import moveIn from "../../images/downloads/Gate-Pass-Moving-in.docx";
```

-- and then in the button --

```
 <a href={moveIn}
    className="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
    download >
     Download
 </a>
```

I'm getting the same error on both tries which is following.
Note - I'm using next with react

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the absolute path of the file.

```
<a href="../../images/downloads/Gate-Pass-Moving-in.docx"
    className="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
    download >
     Download
 </a>
```

Comment: this work but when I make bundle this stop work again

Answer (score 1):

You can't import .docx file into your Reactjs code , isn't js file or jsx file to be imported as in the first try 
But you can set the link 
or you can use this package **[downloadbutton](https://github.com/notablemind/downloadbutton)**

```
    // @demobox
function makeFile() {
  // do some calculations
  return {
    mime: 'text/plain',
    filename: '../../images/downloads/Gate-Pass-Moving-in.docx',
    contents: 'all of the exports',
  }
}


<DownloadButton
  // these classes come from materializecss
  className='waves-effect waves-light btn' 
  genFile={makeFile}/>
```

Another alternative is using [the Javascript File Download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-download) package

```
var fileDownload = require('js-file-download');
fileDownload(data, '../../images/downloads/Gate-Pass-Moving-in.docx');
```

Comment: and what will be in the data parameter? while using js-file-download packege

Comment: Can you share the error ? for DownloadButton package

Comment: I have shared the screenshot of the error in the description.

Comment: I have not used this I have a question in it look at my previous comment